Appending PATH variable with launch.json in VSCode
I have been trying to append PATH variable via launch.json file but unable to do so. I've tried multiple approaches present and suggested online but unable to resolve the issue. Here are the details of the issue:
My folder structure looks like this
- root_folder
  - src
    - app.py
    - mycodefile.py
  - env_var.env

My app.py file has below statement
from src.mycodefile import ABCDclass

my launch.json file looks like this
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "run_main",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "<root_folder_location>",
            "program": "<root_folder_location>/src/app.py",
            "env": {
                "PATH": "${env:PATH};<root_folder_location>"
        },
    ]
}

on running the code, I am getting below error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

The reason for the error is unavailability of root_folder in PATH variable. I want to add this root_folder in PATH variable via launch.json file
